# Easier way in C# for Char output?

Tags: c#

Is there a easier way to output the X the the O in alternate order 8 times? So it would end up looking like this "XOXOXOXO". I mean this works, but its ugly. Thank you.

```
        char x = "X" [0];
        char o = "O" [0]; 

        Console.WriteLine("Should X or O go first: ");
        String answer = Console.ReadLine ();



            if (answer == "x") {


            for( int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {

                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}", x, o, x, o, x, o, x, o);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}", o, x, o, x, o, x, o, x);

                }
```

Comment: Yes, there is a cleaner way

Comment: You can just do `char x = 'X'` instead of `char x = "X"[0]`.  Single quotes for characters and double for strings.

Comment: I suppose the question we have to ask is why are you not just using `Console.Writeline("XOXOXOXO")`? Is this a homework assignment? It's generally considered bad form to ask the internet to do your homework for you.

Comment: @EdB why it is *bad* to ask someone else to do your homework? Waste of time / against the rules of schools may be, but I don't see anything "bad" about it... Plus it is always fun exercise in LINQ and most complicated aspects of language when one asks such question :)

Comment: BTW: `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}{1}{0}{1}{0}{1}", x, o);` is also possible

Comment: @EdB (it is actually rare reasonable homework question where sample code already does what should be done... so not even against SO rules)

Comment: If you're set an assignment, it;s best to do it yourself rather than ask someone else to do it for you (otherwise you're not learning by doing!). It depends on whether the OP has been asked to write a program to output a specific output, or to find the best way of doing so. If it's the former, it's okay, if it's the latter, then it's not.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `%` operator and LINQ:

```
Console.Write(String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => "XO"[i % 2])));
```

Comment: May need to offset by +1 when `answer` is `true` for copy-paste answer... Also if OP would need it for homework answer should be different (but they did not specify that - so LINQ wins)

Comment: I like this, it is straightforward and clear how it works. +1 LINQ wins.

Answer (score 6):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("xo", 4)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ox", 4)));
```

In addition, instead of saying `char x = "X"[0];` you can just say `char x = 'X';` (Although it seems based on the code you provided that you don't need your `char x` and `char o` at all.)

**Edit:** If you do actually want to keep your `char x` and `char o` and use them in the `for` loop, you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Format("{0}{1}", x, o), 4)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Format("{0}{1}", o, x), 4)));
```

Comment: you would need `String.Format("{0}{1}", x, o)` rather than `"xo"` in this case, as they are variables, not literals.

Comment: @austinwernli What does the OP want, then? It seems to me that my code, when placed within the `for` loop, will work just fine.

Comment: The only problem I see is the use of lower case letters instead of upper.

Comment: @austinwernli Do you want to explain what's wrong with my code, or are you just going to keep making unsubstantiated claims?

Comment: okay okay. I take back my statement. However i still am correct that your code will not working while missing an ending parenthesis ;) Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @austinwernli Ah yes, that's true. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

```
/* ... */
for( int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", a % 2 == 0 ? x : o);
}
/* ... */
```

Or, the shorthand:

```
/* ... */
for( int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
     Console.WriteLine("XO"[a % 2]);
}
/* ... */
```

[Modulus Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a StringBuilder to append the text multiple times:

```
Console.WriteLine("Should X or O go first: ");
string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (answer.Equals("X"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        sb.Append("xo");
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        sb.Append("ox");
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

In your case it's not really a problem, but string concatenation isn't great so using a `StringBuilder` is generally a better idea and a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Just felt like adding my 2 cents.

```
Console.WriteLine("XOXOXOXOX".Substring(answer == "x" ? 0 : 1, 8));
```